# c# how do I execute a non query for each item in a list?

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio

My object "Uitslag" has a List property, how do I execute a nonquery for each item in that list.

The code below gives this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The variable name '@Partij_ID' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

```
 public void AddUitslag(Uitslag uitslag)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = Database.Connection)
        {
            VerkiezingRepository VerkiezingRepo = new VerkiezingRepository(new SQLVerkiezingContext());
            string query = "Insert into Uitslag(Naam, Datum, Verkiezing_ID, Partij_ID) values (@Naam, @Datum, @Verkiezing, @Partij_ID)";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naam", uitslag.Naam);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", uitslag.Datum);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Verkiezing",  VerkiezingRepo.GetVerkiezing(uitslag.Verkiezing.Naam).ID);

                foreach (Partij p in uitslag.DeelnemendePartijen)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Partij_ID", p.Afkorting);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the error is because your foreach loop creates the multiple parameters with the same name, which is not allowed. Are you wanting to run one INSERT for each item "p"? If so, then enclose all the code you declare the respository inside the foreach.

Comment: @ADyson It doesn't have to be a foreach loop, but I thought it would work

Comment: sorry amended my comment, see above.

Comment: @ADyson it worked, thank you!

Comment: I've added it as the answer, I'd appreciate it (and it would be useful for future readers) if you'd mark it as the accepted answer - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because your foreach loop creates the multiple parameters with the same name inside the same SqlCommand, which is not allowed. Even though you execute it multiple times, it's still the same SqlCommand object and you just keep on adding to it.

If you are wanting to run one INSERT for each item "p", then enclose all the code after you declare the respository inside the foreach:

```
public void AddUitslag(Uitslag uitslag)
 {
   using (SqlConnection connection = Database.Connection)
   {
        VerkiezingRepository VerkiezingRepo = new VerkiezingRepository(new SQLVerkiezingContext());
        foreach (Partij p in uitslag.DeelnemendePartijen)
        {
            string query = "Insert into Uitslag(Naam, Datum, Verkiezing_ID, Partij_ID) values (@Naam, @Datum, @Verkiezing, @Partij_ID)";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naam", uitslag.Naam);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", uitslag.Datum);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Verkiezing",  VerkiezingRepo.GetVerkiezing(uitslag.Verkiezing.Naam).ID);

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Partij_ID", p.Afkorting);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```